# Oracle Schema Name

Tags: c#, oracle, web-config

How can I include the schema into my connection string inside my web.config.

Answer (score 3):

**The schema is synonymous with user in oracle - you don't specify a schema in the connection string - you specify a username**. Each user may or may not be an owner of database objects (tables, views, procedures, etc). To access the objects owner by another user (schema) you can either:

1. Use a fully qualified name: `SCHEMA.OBJECTNAME`
2. Create a private synonym which aliases to the object: `CREATE SYNONYM mytable 
   FOR otherschema.sometable`
3. Create a public synonym which all users can use to access the object: `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM sometable FOR otherschema.mytable`

Comment: Also, ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'otherschema';

Answer (score 0):

Check out the list of connection strings for Oracle [here](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle).

I could not see any setting that will allow you to specify a schema - guess you need to do this in code.